# Show Gnome-Shell's Dash/Dock on Desktop GNOME 3

Tags: dock, gnome-shell

from almost 4 Years I am trying if Gnome-Shell's Dash can be kept on GNOME 3 Desktop.

Dash I mean when you press Activities button or when you are in Overview.

How is this possible? Can any Gnome-Shell Extension bring this functionality?

Please note that I am not looking for dash-to-dock or dash-to-panel extension.

[image]